# What is this spam on my old question?

Tags: discussion

I notice two separate spambot answers to my question at [Ways to make contact with aliens on a much larger size scale?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20622/ways-to-make-contact-with-aliens-on-a-much-larger-size-scale) that appear to be the same idea, with the same perpetrator though completely different text.

I've never seen this particular spam scam before.  Out of curiosity, has someone with a good sandbox looked at the contents of the linked document?  What's *really* in it?

More to the point, what is it about this question that attracts this bot?  There are *no illustrations* in the Q or anywhere in the thread, at all!  So, the first attempt at claiming copyrighted images is nonsense and I don't see why they would choose a post with no images for this.  The second attempt is more vague about copyrighted material, and although I do quote from a story (my own), there's nothing about markup here that would indicate that something is an extended quote from another source so I doubt the scammer is looking for posts containing pasted materials.

Comment: Regarding scamming, if you're a wolf, you only need one sheep out of their crowd to get a good meal. You can either use a harpoon and aim for a juicy lamb or scream as far as you can to make one tremble in fear and panic. Does this help you answering as to why?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't try to open that link, however the same scam attempt has been scattered on several questions on WB, none of them with images.

I assume whoever is behind that scam wants to filter out the thinking brains and go for those who do not put much thought into clicking links.

Comment: This is the deepest desire of every scammer. I'm hoping the users have been flushed.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want an hacked, turned-evil L.Dutch. Or anyone else. Just the thought of it would be terrible. Glad you didn't put too much thought about whether clicking or not that link :p.

Comment: @Tortliena -- The very thought horrifies. Considering the grief L. Dutch already gets for doing the job, Evil Twin L. Dutch buggers contemplation.

Comment: @elemtilas For that mattered, Evil Twin elemtilas would be pretty bad too.

Comment: @TheDaleks -- HA!! For thát matter, non evil twin elemtilas is bad enough!

Answer (score 1):

This is a phishing/malware campaign affecting many Internet sites, not just Stack Exchange, see for instance [this article](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/copyright-infringement-scam/). Charcoal, the organization behind SmokeDetector, is aware of these posts and they are often [automatically spam flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232). They post these answers on all kinds of questions, you were just unlucky to be hit twice.